# Trying to import mcpi.minecraft on my Mac but I keep getting errors

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, minecraft

I have recent acquired the book adventures in Minecraft and want to give it a try on my Mac. I follow the instructions until it tells me to type this code into my python 2.7:

```
import mcpi.minecraft as minecraft
mc = minecraft.Minecraft.create()
mc.postToChat("Hello Minecraft World")
```

I keep receiving a error stating that no module named `mcpi.minecraft` exists. I checked the folder that stores my program and it does have an `mcpi` folder. Does anybody have the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I ended up not even using IDLE. I just write the commands into a separate terminal window form the one I am running the server on.

I have not written any scripts yet and tried to run them in this way but I am sure it works.

If you use the terminal rather than IDLE (like me) I would pip install mcpi

Answer (score 0):

I use

```py
from mcpi.minecraft import Minecraft
mc = Minecraft.create()
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score -1):

I also decided to read this book and faced the same problem. You just need to save the file by the path: / AdventuresInMinecraft / MyAdventures here you save your file.